# Loading message in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, wolframalpha, pyttsx

I am making a personal assistant in Python 2.7 using the modules 'wikipedia', 'wolframalpha' and 'pyttsx3'. I am making so that the user can ask a question and the computer will then search Wikipedia and Wolfram and speak the answer using Pyttsx. This all works fine but the computer takes a while to fetch the results for the question and I was wondering if it would be possible to add a simple '...loading...' message while is does this. I have added the code below and it would be great if you could respond.

```
import wikipedia
import wolframalpha
import pyttsx3;
engine = pyttsx3.init();

while True:
  my_input = raw_input("Question: ")
  try:
    #wolframalpha code here
    app_id = "Q2HXJ5-GYYYX6PYYP"
    client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
    res = client.query(my_input)
    answer = next(res.results).text 
    print(answer)
    engine.say(answer);
    engine.runAndWait();


  except:
      try:
        #wikipedia code here
        print(wikipedia.summary(my_input))
      except:
        print("Sorry nothing can be found from your query")
```

Comment: why don't you just print loading before the api call

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to use bare `except`. You should name the exception(s) you want to catch, otherwise you might catch more than you intend, which can make it hard to debug.

Comment: Do you want to print `loading ....` multiple times, or just once?  (In other words, is there a reason that this is not just as trivial as Kalyan's comment?)

Comment: I would like to just print loading and then once the answer has been fetched have it printed to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove `Loading...` after the API call is completed, you can just move the cursor to the start of that line using the escape code `ESC[1000D`. Note that you must use `sys.stdout.write()` as opposed to print here, as we want this all to happen on the same line.

```
import sys

// Before API Call
sys.stdout.write("Loading...")
sys.stdout.flush()

// After API Call
sys.stdout.write(u"\u001b[1000D")
print "Done!     "
```

Note the `u` proceeding the double-quoted string. This is required in `Python 2.x`, as it includes special characters, but can be omitted in `Python 3`.

(By the way, the extra spaces on *`Done`* are only there so that the string is longer than *`Loading...`* so that it replaces it completely, without leaving *`ng...`* on the end)